# Is it possible to embed a bash variable in rsyslog message?

Tags: bash, syslog, rsyslog

We've setup a central log server using rsyslog. I was just wondering if it's possible to send the ip address along with the syslog message from the client. 
I'm sending the message using a template and tried using `%fromhost-ip%`. As expected it's showing up as `127.0.0.1` on the remote server.
So I was wondering is there any way we can embed a bash variable in the 
rsyslog.conf. 
The only other alternative I see is to hardcode the ip which doesn't look too nice.

I'm currently using the below template.

```
$template linux_err,"<%PRI%>%TIMESTAMP% %source% %syslogtag% %smg%"
```

Guess using the `%fromhost-ip%` on the receiving server is the only option.

Comment: If you use `%hostname%` on the sender you should get something unique, if you have configured a hostname. Or use `%fromhost-ip%` in a format template on the server receiving the messages to change the message.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly written in the documentation that if you are receiving messages from the local system, then you will get 127.0.0.1 as the ip.

Here, http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/properties.html

try sending it from some other system. It works for me.

Or else, if IP is not important to you and you just want to distinguish the host, use %hostname% property.